# Cannot use JSX with nodejs ESM module loader

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I attempted to run a simple block of code featuring React "render" method , but the browser didn't display the text.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

I'm using VS Code as editor therefore I typed the "Run and Debug Node.js" command. It came up with the warning below

```
(node:3004) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
```

Setting "type:module" in the package.json file solved the problem but on the other side another problem arised

```
(node:18968) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.    
warning.js:32
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
 at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:81:18)
 at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:37:21)
```

That won't allow me to write any tags whatsover. What am I missing and how can I solve it? Below is the index.html file and the file structure

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> React Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: The file structure]

Comment: Did you set up your project with `create-react-app`?

Comment: Yes I did and the standard React project that comes with it loaded successfully

Comment: I guess JSX support is missing. Try `React.createElement('h1', null, 'Hello World')` instead of `<h1>Hello World</h1>` to confirm. See https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#quickly-try-jsx

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to download `debugger for Chrome` in vs code, setup `launch.json` file and run react app that way? [More about it here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/reactjs-tutorial)

Comment: can you share your dependencies of package.json

Comment: @XHOxha what does the `.vscode` folder inside `src` and what brings `index.html` and `index.js` inside it ?

Comment: "the **browser** didn't display" + "Run and Debug **Node.js**"? And you expect to see something in the browser? If it's not a typo that means your're running the node, not a browser.

Answer (score 1):

JSX isn't a valid JavaScript syntax and it isn't part of any ECMAScript specification as well at the current time. NodeJS supporting ESM does not mean it supports JSX natively.

[JSX are expected to be transpiled into a valid JavaScript on build/compile time using tools like babel](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/). If you are using React, the most simple way to do this is to use babel with [`@babel/preset-react`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react), which will transpile all JSX into `React.createElement()` calls. You can then run the code generated by babel using node.

To give you a clearer picture, here is a [Babel online REPL](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd4BhXSGpG-AXjgAoBKOJwB8cADwATYADchACSQAbBRDgB3aAvGiA9JJmkgA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=true&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.11.1&externalPlugins=) that you can play with to see how your code are transpiled by babel.

A common setup for react apps that is going to be run on the browser is like:

1. Use webpack to bundle your app
2. Configure webpack to use `babel-loader` so it transpiles your code into something that browsers can run
3. Use the generated javascript bundle on browser

Comment: That is not a solution for Node.js environment, it is a good solution for compiling the code and then run it. Nodejs native esm requires a loader for JSX.

Comment: The concept is largely similar with node environment. The code with JSX would still need to be transpiled for it to be able to run in Node environment. If you are bundling using webpack, the difference is that you only need to set the target to "node" instead of the default "web".

Comment: Again, that's not a solution for a loader for nodejs native esm. see https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_experimental_loaders

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have `.vscode` folder in your `src` folder and it contains `index.html` and `index.js` files.

I think you need to move your `index.js` file from `.vscode` folder to `src` and delete `.vscode` folder. Or just create a new app with npm.

Answer (score 0):

that folder structure came out after using create-react-app?

btw, try to return the component with React.createElement()

```
return React.createElement('div', {className: 'shopping-list'},
  React.createElement('h1', /* ... h1 children ... */),
  React.createElement('ul', /* ... ul children ... */)
);
```

as docs says "The render method returns a description of what you want to see on the screen. React takes the description and displays the result. In particular, render returns a React element, which is a lightweight description of what to render. Most React developers use a special syntax called “JSX” which makes these structures easier to write. The  syntax is transformed at build time to React.createElement('div')."

check this out
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement

----- add on
You can now import `.js` file in node **v12.x**, in 2 steps:

- after adding the following line in your `package.json` file:

  ```js
  // package.json
  {
    "type": "module"
  }
  ```
- you need to add `--experimental-modules` flag when launching the script:

  ```sh
  node --experimental-modules index.js
  ```

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_commonjs_json_and_native_modules